# What am I doing wrong here... Product of Array Except Self

Tags: python, arrays, list

**Question:**

Given an integer array `nums`, return an array answer such that `answer[i]` is equal to the product of all the elements of `nums` except `nums[i]`.

The product of any prefix or suffix of `nums` is guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit integer.

You must write an algorithm that runs in `O(n)` time and without using the division operation.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4]
Output: [24,12,8,6]
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: nums = [-1,1,0,-3,3]
Output: [0,0,9,0,0]
```

**Constraints:**

```
2 <= nums.length <= 105

-30 <= nums[i] <= 30
```

The product of any prefix or suffix of nums is guaranteed to fit in a **32-bit integer**.

Follow up: Can you solve the problem in O(1) extra space complexity? (The output array does not count as extra space for space complexity analysis.)

My Code:

```
class Solution:
    def productExceptSelf(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        
        a=[1 for i in range(len(arr))]
        
        product_left=1
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            a[i] = product_left*a[i-1]
            product_left *= arr[i]
            
        product_right=1
        for i in range(len(arr)-1,-1,-1):
            a[i]*=product_right
            product_right*=arr[i]
        return a
```

**Your input**

```
[1,2,3,4]
[-1,1,0,-3,3]
```

**Output**

```
[24,12,8,12]
[0,0,-9,0,0]
```

**Expected**

```
[24,12,8,6]
[0,0,9,0,0]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to handle the test cases when there is a 0 in the list.

I have solved this question using the below logic.

```
class Solution:
    def productExceptSelf(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        p = 1
        ans = []
        zero_count = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == 0:
                zero_count += 1
                continue
            p *= nums[i]
    
        for i in nums:
            if i == 0:
                if zero_count == 1:
                    ans.append(p)
                else:
                    ans.append(0)
            else:
                if zero_count == 0:
                    ans.append(p//i)
                else:
                    ans.append(0)
                    
        return ans
```

You have to count the numbers of zero and after that divide with element itself.